# Flagging a duplicate answer

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, specific-answer

I just noticed that one of my flags had been declined stating:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

Fair enough, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31646259/1324033) openly admits that the answer is from a duplicate question...

Before flagging as not an answer (the answer should be a comment since the user can't close questions yet). I left a comment for others to see and VTC'd the question with the given duplicate.

Is there anything more I could have done (or done better) with this flag or is this answer actually acceptable?

Comment: In general, moderators will decline flags on accepted answers except for very a very small set of circumstances. Best you can do is bring it up on chat, or bring the post up for a discussion of its merits here. If the answer is not accepted, very low quality flags go further because they put the answers into the Low Quality Posts Review Queue.

Comment: @TinyGiant - I'm not sure if an accepted answer should have any relevance on a moderators decision but I can see how it could be... but then that wouldn't match the reason that was given for my declined flag

Answer (score 1):

That answer should be simply downvoted and deleted, as it just duplicates the code of the accepted answer in the duplicate target.
Also, **it wasn't marked as a quote**, even though it linked to the source, doing so would have increased the chance of getting it deleted.

Should you have used a Not-an-answer-flag? Risky, since you cannot point out what exactly alerted you.
Still, the comment *should* have been enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's fine given that:

1. Answer is providing a reference (link) to the original answer in a upfront manner.
2. Answer is valid and answers the original question.
3. Answer was the first answer posted to that question.

It'd be ideal if the question was closed before anybody had to answer it, but I don't see much of a problem with this. It might be that this answer was the reason question was closed as duplicate to begin with.

Comment: What your answer eludes to is that it would be acceptable for anyone to click on a potential duplicate link, copy the answer whilst giving credit, and then gain reputation from doing so which isn't something I will ever be ok with.

Comment: @Sayse: You could try, but you can't answer questions when they are closed as a duplicate.

Comment: _"It might be that this answer was the reason question was closed as duplicate to begin with."_ <- I agree.

Comment: @Cerbrus - That particular answer was made after someone had posted a link to the duplicate, but before the 5 close votes had closed the question.